# Conditionally extracting outer key-value in a JSON using JsonPath

Tags: java, json, jsonpath

Here's my JSON:

```
{
    "status": false,
    "responseData": [{
        "data": {
            "value": "value",
            "label": "label"
        },
        "type": "HEADING"
    }, {
        "data": {
            "section": "SECTION1",
            "post": {}
        },
        "type": "POST"
    }, {
        "data": {
            "section": "SECTION1",
            "post": {}
        },
        "type": "POST"
    }, {
        "data": {
            "section": "SECTION1",
            "post": {}
        },
        "type": "POST"
    }, {
        "data": {
            "section": "SECTION1",
            "value": "value",
            "label": "label",
            "type": "POSTS_LIST",
            "headerDetails": {
                "value": "value",
                "label": "label"
            },
            "metaData": {
                "params": {
                    "param1": "value1",
                    "param2": "value2"
                }
            }
        },
        "type": "CALL_TO_ACTION"
    }],
    "message": "OK"
}
```

I'm using [Jayway JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) for data extraction.

Problem: I would like to fetch all the `type` values (e.g. `CALL_TO_ACTION`) based on the section name (e.g. `SECTION1`).

What I tried at https://jsonpath.curiousconcept.com: `$.responseData[*].[?(@.section=='SECTION1')].type`, but that gives me `POSTS_LIST` (obviously!), which is the internal `type` and not the external `type` attribute I'm looking for.

Comment: @Wayne Hey, thanks! Could you please, if you know, mention the GSon way to achieve this?

Comment: Create a container class, lets call it container: `class Container{}` which would need variable definitions for `String status` and `ResponseData[] responseData` now declare `class ResponseData` with variable definition `Data data`, now create `class Data` with variable definition `String type`;; After you've done this, `Container c = (Container)(new GSon().fromJSon(jsonStringOrFile))` then just iterate through the array in the ResponseData array.

Comment: scratch that, you don't need to go as deep as the data class, as the type is held within the ResponseData instance, so declare `String type` in the ResponseData class, then iterate through the responseData array, reading the `type` variable in each. Apologies for that mistake, I apparently didn't read the JSON code section well enough before posting the comment.

Comment: @Wayne Thanks a lot, but seems like too much of an effort! :P
I think I'll stick to find a Jayway JsonPath solution for this.

Comment: Guess I left out a little when answering your question... Third post so I'm kinda butthurt after noticing that... because you want to retrieve it based on the section name, rather than based purely on the type variable, we will still need the `Data` class and it will require that you've defined the variable `String section` and the `ResponseData` class will require that `Data data` be defined. To iterate through and get the section type for the desired section;

Comment: `public String getSectionType(String sectionName) {
  for (ResponseData r : ContainerInstance.responseData) {
    if(r == null || r.data == null)
      continue;
    return r.type;
  }
  return nullOrEmptyStringHere;
}`
Also, I apologize for the complexity of all of this, that's partially my fault. and I understand your decision, however this option is now available for your usage, should you change your mind. Sorry I couldn't be of immediate assistance.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot @Wayne! Never mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to filter on a child level attribute and then return a parent level attribute.

To be more specific, in the following example ...

```
{
    "data": {
        "section": "SECTION1",
        "value": "value",
        "label": "label",
        "type": "POSTS_LIST",
        "headerDetails": {
            "value": "value",
            "label": "label"
        },
        "metaData": {
            "params": {
                "param1": "value1",
                "param2": "value2"
            }
        }
    },
    "type": "CALL_TO_ACTION"
}
```

... the child level attribute is `"section": "SECTION1"` and the parent level attribute is `"type": "CALL_TO_ACTION"`.

This is **not** currently supported by JayWay JsonPath though there is an [open issue](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath/issues/287) relating to it. You could perhaps upvote the issue and/or consider raising a PR for it.

Alternatively, you'll have to use a JSON deserializer (such as Gson suggested by @Wayne) to deserialize your JSON to a Map (or similar) construct which you can then filter and having found your match walk back up the tree to find the data you wish to retrieve.

Comment: Thank you for answering the question. I've upvoted the issue on GitHub.
Are you aware of any other approach/library (other than Jayway) that would help me out here?

Comment: I'm not aware of a JsonPath implementation which can handle 'foward and backward' movement. I _think_ using Gson or Jackson to deserialize into a construct which you can then filter and interrogate is your only solution here.

Comment: Alright, thanks again! I'll try one of these solutions.